# Declare async function/promise in object

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

I have a function that returns an object with "exported" functions. In these exported functions I want to use promises.

```
var DATABASE = (function () {
  var exports = {};
  
  exports.query = function(filter = {}) {
    return true;
  }

  return exports;
}());

console.log(DATABASE.query());
```

I tried to make this function async. But I get DATABASE.query is not a function.

```
var DATABASE = (async function () {
  var exports = {};
  
  exports.query = await function(filter = {}) {
      return true;
  }

  return exports;
}());

console.log(DATABASE.query());
```

I tried it with promises and it seems like it work, but I think await/async is better coding.

```
var DATABASE = (function () {
  var exports = {};
  
  exports.query = function(filter = {}) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      resolve(true);
    });
  }
  return exports;
}());

DATABASE.query().then(function(result) { 
  console.log(result);
});
```

Can you help me to transform this into async/await?

Comment: If the IIFE is an `async` function then `DATABASE` is a *promise* of the object. In this case there's no point it being `async`, because `await function() { ... }` doesn't make any sense; it's the `query` function that should be `async`.

Comment: can you explain a litte bit more? It is possilbe to use it async await?

Comment: Putting `async` on a function definition makes it return a Promise.  So look at what you did to your `DATABASE`

Comment: If you mean to make `query` async, then you should not `await` it when assigning it to your export. `exports.query = async() => { await blah(); return true; }`

Comment: Is it possible? Yes. But the *way* you're doing it makes no sense. `async` functions *always* return promises, there's no need for the IIFE to be an `async` function.

Comment: you probably wanted to use await in inside the function(filter ={})... Just like with promises - you created promises inside

Comment: ok than better way with promise?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your `query` method asynchronous, not the IIFE used (unnecessarily) for the module pattern:

```
const DATABASE = (function () {
  const exports = {};
  
  exports.query = async function(filter = {}) {
//                ^^^^^
      return true;
  };

  return exports;
}());

console.log(DATABASE.query());
```

Comment: but with this i get promise returned not the value true.

Comment: But you *wanted* `query` to return a promise, didn't you? Of course, to log the result instead of the promise, you would use `DATABASE.query().then(console.log)` or `console.log(await DATABASE.query())`, but from the demonstration in your question you seemed to already know that.

Comment: Yes but await didnt work seems like await don't Work in the global scope. So only then() would ne possible.

Comment: Yes. Makes no difference for the implementation of `query` though.